# What band is this?

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

What music band does this HTML snippet represent?

```
<i style="color:#000">PPPP</i>
```

Comment: An easy one for the Friday

Comment: Yes, but really fun :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> Black Eyed Peas.

Explanation:

> We have four Ps in a tag that makes them black and italicizes them. Black Italicized Ps = Black Eyed Peas. Also, there were 4 band members, thus 4 Ps.